Airflow docker: Connect airflow docker with SQL Server
I need to connect Airflow with SQL Server (I run Airflow using Docker). But it seem doesn't work.
I installed the mssql package (by running pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql),
and I double checked that the package is installed. But when I found providers on aiflow UI, I didn't see "apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssq", so I couldn't find SQL server on conn type option. Do I need to add some command in dockerfile or docker_compose ?
